# Как сохранить модель перебором?

Tags: yii, yii2

Хочу сохранить двуязычный контент. Форма:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($aboutLang_ru, 'title')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($aboutLang_ru, 'content')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($aboutLang_en, 'title')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($aboutLang_en, 'content')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

И контроллер

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Post();
    $aboutLang_ru = new PostLang();
    $aboutLang_en = new PostLang();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->save()) {

                $dbPost = new PostLang();
                $dbPost->title = $aboutLang_ru->title;
                $dbPost->content = $aboutLang_ru->content;
                $dbPost->lang_id = ////////;
                $dbPost->post_id = $model->id;
                $dbPost->save();

        }
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('_form', [
                    'model' => $model, 'aboutLang_ru' => $aboutLang_ru, 'aboutLang_en' => $aboutLang_en]);
    }
}
```

Вот как мне сделать перебор в сохранении, чтобы сохраняло сначала из $aboutLang_ru, а потом из $aboutLang_en? Разные записи в таблице и с разным lang_id, но с одинаковым post_id?

Answer (score 1):

Извините,я наверное не понял Ваш вопрос.
А что вам мешает сохранить две разных инстанса модели Postlang просто последовательно? Указав каждой соответствующие значения полей?
 if ($model->save()) {

```
            $dbPost = new PostLang();
            $dbPost->title = $aboutLang_ru->title;
            $dbPost->content = $aboutLang_ru->content;
            $dbPost->lang_id = ////////;
            $dbPost->post_id = $model->id;
            $dbPost->save();

            $dbPost2 = new PostLang();
            $dbPost2->title = $aboutLang_en->title;
            $dbPost2->content = $aboutLang_en->content;
            $dbPost2->lang_id = ////////;
            $dbPost2->post_id = $model->id;
            $dbPost2->save();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

А можно даже проще, чем вариант описанный выше:

```
if($model->save()) {

        $dbPost = new PostLang();
        $dbPost->title = $aboutLang_ru->title;
        $dbPost->content = $aboutLang_ru->content;
        $dbPost->lang_id = 1;
        $dbPost->post_id = $model->id;
        $dbPost->save();

        //сбрасывает состояние записи, к новой, теперь вместо перезаписи,
        //сохранится новая запись 
        $dbPost->isNewRecord = 1;
        $dbPost->id=null

        //меняем только те значения которые нужно
        $dbPost->title = $aboutLang_en->title;
        $dbPost->content = $aboutLang_en->content;
        $dbPost->lang_id = 2;

        //сохраняем
        $dbPost->save();

}
```

Comment: Первичный ключ удалять еще нужно. Но для эстетичности я бы клонированием сделал второй инстанс, а дальше то, что Вы предложили.

Comment: Да, про слона то я и забыл, подправил.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам все же принципиально перебором

```
if ($model->save()) {
    $langs = [$aboutLang_ru, $aboutLang_en];
    foreach($langs as $lang){
        $dbPost = new PostLang();
        $dbPost->title = $lang->title;
        $dbPost->content = $lang->content;
        $dbPost->lang_id = $lang->id;
        $dbPost->post_id = $model->id;
        $dbPost->save();
    }
```

}